# Python / PyGame: Find pixel by colorcode

Tags: python, colors, find, pygame, pixel

Is there a way to find a pixel (inside a surface / image) by color?
like:

```
img = python.image.load("image.gif").convert()
img.find((255, 255, 255)) >> (50, 100) = white pixel
```

If you don't know what I mean, feel free to ask.
Thank you!

Comment: No, there isn't. But you can loop over each pixel in the 2D matrix and find them yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def findPixel(img, r, g, b):
    for x in range(0, img.get_width()):
        for y in range(0, img.get_height()):
            pixel = img.get_at((x, y))
            if pixel[0] >= r and pixel[1] >= g and pixel[2] >= b:
                return pixel
    return None
```

This is written of the top of my head. Passing in your image object should word. If not you'll have to input the `image.surface` object reference. But the idea of iterating over X and Y should work in theory.

- [Here's some references to `get_width()`etc that you'll need to use](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)
- A useful feature for speed optimization is `get_rect()`

Pygame host no function like this, but it does supply you with the ability to get or iterate over pixel positions.

There is a faster way and that is to store the entire image-array prior to the loop and iterate over that array instead of calling the `get_at` function i believe, however I don't use Pygame these days so i can't test the optimization difference of the two implementations so i'll leave it at this and leave the optimization to you.

**If you're interested in finding all the color values corresponding to your parameters** (thanks SuperBiasedMan):

```
def findPixel(img, r, g, b):
    found = []
    for x in range(0, img.width):
        for y in range(0, img.height):
            pixel = img.get_at((x, y))
            if pixel[0] >= r and pixel[1] >= g and pixel[2] >= b:
                found.append((x, y))
    return found
```

Note that this will be slower, but you'll find all the pixels in one iteration.

Comment: Also you could modify this to return a list of pixels with that colour just by creating an empty list then changing  `return pixel` to `list.append(pixel)` and then changing `return None` to return `yourListName`.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan You are correct, it's slower by nature but it's worth putting in there. Updated my answer! :)

Comment: Well, if there's no faster way, I'm going to do this (a little bit different). My idea is, to show a camera recording (many images per second) and mark the darkest object all the time.

Comment: @d0n.key I've done similar things, you won't get much FPS out of Python the basic ways. But you could build a C module that does the looping and checking the colors and returning a array of pixel positions :) Also [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org) is faster for these kinds of operations.